# Accessors of type class?

Tags: coq, typeclass

from what I know, a type class in Coq is "almost" a record, with magic around for type inference.

Although I am not aware anybody saying it explicitly, I have the feeling of type classes can do whatever records can do.

However, this feeling lead me to some problem with accessors of type class, which seems standard with record:

```
Require Import List. 
Set Printing All.
Set Implicit Arguments.

(* Record version that works: *)

Record Foo_r (A_r: Type) := { getter_r : list A_r; }.   
Definition foo_r : Foo_r nat := {| getter_r := 2::nil |}.
Compute (getter_r foo_r).

(* Type class version that does not work: *)

Class Foo_t (A_t: Type) := { getter_t : list A_t; }.   
Instance foo_t : Foo_t nat := {| getter_t := 2::nil |}.
Compute (getter_t foo_t).
```

It is interesting that *getter_r* and *getter_t* have a very similar function signature, and the fact that *Foo_t* is indeed just a record:

```
Print getter_r.
(* fun (A_r : Type) (f : Foo_r A_r) => let (getter_r) := f in getter_r
 : forall A_r : Type, Foo_r A_r -> list A_r *)

Print getter_t.
(* fun (A_t : Type) (Foo_t0 : Foo_t A_t) => let (getter_t) := Foo_t0 in getter_t
 : forall A_t : Type, Foo_t A_t -> list A_t *)
```

May I ask that, conceptually, is this a design decision to disallow accessors for type class? or I just use it wrong? thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check the type of `getter_t` using `About getter_t.` you will see:

> ```
> getter_t : forall (A_t : Type) (_ : Foo_t A_t), list A_t
>
> Arguments A_t, Foo_t are implicit and maximally inserted
> ```

`Foo_t` is *maximally inserted*, meaning that if you just mention `getter_t` with no further information, Coq should be able to infer the argument of this type. In other words, saying

```
Compute getter_t foo_t.
```

is the same as

```
Compute @getter_t _ _ foo_t.
```

which is not correct because `@getter_t` takes only two arguments (`@`-notation means "I'm going to list all the arguments, including the implicit ones").

You can say

```
Compute @getter_t _ foo_t.
```

Or just

```
Compute getter_t.
```